# JS/jQuery library adds style to all children which is not accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout, grid

I am using this JS lib - [Magic Grid](https://github.com/e-oj/Magic-Grid) to add  a nice layout to items on the page. 
This is body:

```
<div id="grid" class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="item1"></div>
       <div class="item2"></div>
       <div class="item3"></div>
       <div class="item4"></div>
   </div>
</div>
// Magic Grid:
<script>
   let magicGrid = new MagicGrid({
     container: "#grid", // Required. Can be a class, id, or an HTMLElement
     static: true, // Required for static content. Default: false.
     items: 10, // Required for dynamic content. Initial number of items in the container.
     gutter: 0, // Optional. Space between items. Default: 25(px).
     maxColumns: 3, // Optional. Maximum number of columns. Default: Infinite.
     animate: true, // Optional. Animate item positioning. Default: false.
   });
   magicGrid.listen();
<script>
```

the thing is, that this lib sets styles `transform` and `position` to all the **children** within a container with id `grid`. The result will be something like this (px are approximate for this example):

```
<div id="grid" class="container" style="position: realitve; height: 980px">
   <div class="row" style="transform: 0px, 0px;"> <!- here have to be no style attr
       <div class="item1" style="transform: 135px, 0px; position: realitve; ..."></div>
       <div class="item2" style="transform: 233px, 110px; position: realitve; ..."></div>
       <div class="item3" style="transform: 459px, 230px; position: realitve; ..."></div>
       <div class="item4" style="transform: 670px, 397px; position: realitve; ..."></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

By each window resize, the position of items will be recalculated to correspond the responsiveness to all different devices and window sizes.

And here comes the problem. Without `row` everything dances perfect, except phones. The layout is  shifted to the right a little bit,  and the only thing that helps, is this div with row class.

But if the window is resized, this `row` div also gets `transform` and layout brakes everywhere. The items are positioned somewhere between footer and keyboard.
Is there a way somehow to have this row div, but to protect/prevent lib from customizing its style attribute?

I've tried to run a script on window resize to check whether row has attr `style` and remove it if true, but unfortunatelly that didn't help at all.

Or the only option is to refactor the code in lib accordingly to my needs? [Magic Grid index file](https://github.com/e-oj/Magic-Grid/blob/master/src/index.js). Not even sure if that possible.

**UPDATE!
Solved.**

So the  problem was in constructor. I didn't initialize configuration `useTransform`. As soon as I initialized `useTransfrom` : `false`, the Layout began to be responsive on all devices WITHOUT `row` div. Kinda weird feeling, because I don't really understand the connection between `useTransform:false;` with no row and `useTransfrom: true;` with row.

Comment: The `row` class is presumably needed by the library to know which DIVs are grid rows.

Comment: And the style attributes are the way Magic Grid does its work.

Comment: actually I can delete div with row class and grid works perfectly , **except** on mobile devices. There will be only 1 column of items and this column is shifted approx 5-10 px to the right (because of item paddings). But when I paste div row in chrome devTool without any styles, the column will be placed in the middle. And it has to be so.
If I rotate/resize the view with row div already inside, the position of everythiing will be recalculated and this row div gets style attr with transofrm and layout collapses